# Save apikey between sessions

Tags: javascript, html, http, api-key

I'm making a little client-side web app for MagicCardMarket.eu. It's just javascript and html. The user has to log in using his username and apikey, though I was wondering what's the best way to save these between sessions?

It's the first time I make this kind of web app. It's also the first time I use anything like this apikey, so I wasn't sure what to Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage`.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key','value');
var value = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

### So what is it?

> This is a global object (sessionStorage) that maintains a storage area
>   that's available for the duration of the page session. A page session
>   lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page
>   reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause
>   a new session to be initiated.

Comment: glad to have helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

use session storage. It stores values as key, value pairs. 
To set the value to session use

```
sessionStorage.name = "Use Name";
sessionStorage.APIKey = "Use APIKey";
```

To Get the values from session storage:

```
var name = sessionStorage.name;
var APIKey = sessionStorage.APIKey;
```

Note: Name/value pairs are always stored as strings. Remember to convert them to another format when needed!